# Visual Studio Code Copy working but not properly

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi my visual studio code does this weird single line paste whenever I copy a code from a pdf or any other sources.

this picture below is what I copied from
[image: bar]

this is what happens when I paste my code
[image: bar2]

Not really sure what made it this way but I have tried reinstalling, deleting the cache, all the files related to visual studio code but it doesn't work.

The reason why I am asking this because it used to work and my friends that use vscode doesn't have this problem.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: pdf files don't have a sense of lines, every word or group of words are positioned absolute, your lucky the parts are sequentially placed in the pdf

Comment: hmm but I am not too sure why my friends one is working...

Comment: You might try toggling the `Editor: Format on Paste` setting to see if it makes a difference.  And are you copying with/without formatting which are options in some applcations?

Comment: then you need to compare the `settings.json` files, the global and the project ones, and try to disable all extensions on both machines and see if that makes a difference. you can try and install the `insider` version of VSC without any extension or setting changed from the default